Making the event calendar persistent, as updated events revert to today's date unless i navigate manually
I am working with the @event-calendar library. The calendar supports fetching, updating, and deleting events, as well as updating events by resizing or using drag-and-drop. However, whenever I update an event from previous dates, it does not stay in its updated position; instead, it reverts to today's date. Additionally, there is a date picker that works, but when a date is selected, the calendar does not automatically navigate to that date. here is the code
import React, { useEffect, useRef ,useState,useMemo} from 'react';
import Calendar from '@event-calendar/core';
import DayGrid from '@event-calendar/day-grid';
import Interaction from '@event-calendar/interaction';
import List from '@event-calendar/list';
import ResourceTimeGrid from '@event-calendar/resource-time-grid';
import TimeGrid from '@event-calendar/time-grid';
import ResourceTimeline from '@event-calendar/resource-timeline';
import '@event-calendar/core/index.css';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import moment from 'moment';

  const EventCalendarWrapper = ({ events = [],onEventUpdate, onEventCreate, openForm, openCreateForm , calendarStartDate, calendarEndDate}) => {
  const calendarContainer = useRef(null);
  const [changedView, setChangedView] = useState('timeGridWeek'); // To keep track of current view
  const calendarRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  const user =useSelector((state) => state.auth);const handleDateChange = (info) => {
    console.log("Complete info object:", info);
    if (info && info.startStr) {
      const newDate = moment(info.startStr).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log("New date:", newDate);
      console.log("current bef", currentDate); 

      // Directly update currentDate without the unnecessary check
      setCurrentDate(newDate); 

      console.log("newdate", newDate);
      console.log("currentdate", currentDate); 
    } else {
      console.warn("Invalid info object received:", info);
    }
};
 const mappedEvents = events.map(event => ({
    _id: event._id,
    start:  event.start_time || event.start,
    end:  event.end_time || event.end,
    title: event.title,
    color: event.color,
    allDay: event.allDay,
    resourceIds: [
      ...(event.assigned_resources?.assigned_to || []).map(user => user?._id || 'undefined'),
      ...(event.assigned_resources?.tools || []).map(tool => tool?._id || ''),
      ...(event.assigned_resources?.materials || []).map(material => material?._id || ''),
    ],
    extendedProps: {
      _id: event._id,
      image: event.image,
      notes: event.notes,
      status: event.status,
      assigned_resources: {
        assigned_to: event.assigned_resources?.assigned_to || [],
        tools: event.assigned_resources?.tools || [],
        materials: event.assigned_resources?.materials || [],
      },
    },
  }));
  const groupedAssignedResources = useMemo(() => [
  {
    id: 'assignedUsers',
    title: 'Assigned Users',
    children: events.flatMap(event =>
      (event.assigned_resources?.assigned_to || []).map(user => ({
        id: user?._id || 'undefined',
        title: `${user?.first_name || 'Unknown'} ${user?.last_name || 'Unknown'}`,
        parent: 'assignedUsers',
      }))
    ),
  },
  {
    id: 'tools',
    title: 'Tools',
    children: events.flatMap(event =>
      (event.assigned_resources?.tools || []).map(tool => ({
        id: tool?._id || '',
        title: tool?.tool_name || 'Unknown Tool',
        parent: 'tools',
      }))
    ),
  },
  {
    id: 'materials',
    title: 'Materials',
    children: events.flatMap(event =>
      (event.assigned_resources?.materials || []).map(material => ({
        id: material?._id || '',
        title: material?.material_name || 'Unknown Material',
        parent: 'materials',
      }))
    ),
  },
  ],[events]);
  // Combine parent categories and children into a single array
  // const assigned_resources = [
  // ...groupedAssignedResources,
  // ];
  // Memoize assigned_resources to prevent unnecessary re-renders
  const assigned_resources = useMemo(() => [...groupedAssignedResources], [groupedAssignedResources]);
const adjustTimeForBackend = (time, timezoneOffset) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + timezoneOffset);
    return date.toISOString();
  };  const handleViewChange = (view) => {
    setChangedView(view);
    if (calendarRef.current) {
      calendarRef.current.setOption('view', view);
      
      if (view === 'year') {
        const { start, end } = getYearRange();
        calendarRef.current.setOption('visibleRange', { start, end });
      }
    }
  };
  
  const getYearRange = () => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const startOfYear = new Date(currentYear, 0, 1); // Jan 1
    const endOfYear = new Date(currentYear, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59); // Dec 31
  
    // Validate the dates
    if (isNaN(startOfYear.getTime()) || isNaN(endOfYear.getTime())) {
      console.error('Invalid date range!');
    }
  
    return { start: startOfYear, end: endOfYear };
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (calendarRef.current) {
      calendarRef.current.setOption('events', mappedEvents);
      calendarRef.current.setOption('resources', assigned_resources);
    }
  }, [mappedEvents, assigned_resources]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!calendarContainer.current) return;
    // Destroy existing calendar to prevent multiple instances
    if (calendarRef.current) {
      calendarRef.current.destroy();
    }
    console.log("calendarContainer.current",calendarContainer.current);
    console.log("calendarRef.curren",calendarRef.curren)
    // if (!calendarRef.current) {
    calendarRef.current = new Calendar({
      target: calendarContainer.current,
      props: {
        plugins: [DayGrid, TimeGrid, List, ResourceTimeGrid, ResourceTimeline, Interaction],
        options: {
          initialDate: currentDate,
          view: changedView,
          selectable: true,
          editable: true,
          eventStartEditable: true,
          eventDurationEditable: true,
          events: mappedEvents,
          resources: assigned_resources,
          headerToolbar: {
            start: 'today,prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'year,month,week,day,list,resource,timeline',
          },
          datesSet: handleDateChange, // Attach handler
          views: {
            listYear: {
              type: 'list',
              duration: { months: 24 },
              buttonText: 'Year',
            },
          },
          customButtons: {
            month: {
              text: 'Month',
              click: () => handleViewChange('dayGridMonth'),
            },
            week: {
              text: 'Week',
              click: () => handleViewChange('timeGridWeek'),
            },
            day: {
              text: 'Day',
              click: () => handleViewChange('timeGridDay'),
              
            },
            list: {
              text: 'List',
              click: () => handleViewChange('listWeek'),
            },
            year: {
              text: 'Year',
              click: () => handleViewChange('listYear'),
            },
            resource: {
              text: 'Resource',
              click: () => handleViewChange('resourceTimeGridWeek'),
              
            },
            timeline: {
              text: 'Timeline',
              click: () => handleViewChange('resourceTimelineDay'), // Corrected view name
            },
          },
          select: (info) => {
            if (user.access_level < 3) {
              toast.error('You do not have permission to create events.');
              return;
            }
            const { start, end, resource } = info;
            const timezoneOffset = 3; // Adjust this value based on the expected timezone
            const adjustedStartTime = adjustTimeForBackend(start, timezoneOffset);
            const adjustedEndTime = adjustTimeForBackend(end, timezoneOffset);
            const generatedId = uuidv4();
            const newEvent = {
              _id: generatedId,
              start_time: adjustedStartTime,
              end_time: adjustedEndTime,
              color_code: 'green',
              title: 'new task',
              resource,
            };
            openCreateForm(newEvent);
          },
          dateClick: (info) => {
            console.log("user",user);
            if (user.access_level < 3) {
              toast.error('You do not have permission to create events.');
              return;
            }
            const timezoneOffset = 3; 
            const adjustedStartTime = adjustTimeForBackend(info.date, timezoneOffset);
            const newEvent = {
              _id: uuidv4(),
              start_time: adjustedStartTime,
              color_code: 'green',
              title: 'new task',
            };
            openCreateForm(newEvent); // Open form with pre-filled start time
          },
          eventClick: (info) => {
            if (user.access_level < 2) {
              toast.error('You do not have permission to create events.');
              return;
            }
             // Extract event details
  const { event } = info;
  const { extendedProps } = event;
  // Ensure `_id` is extracted properly, either from extendedProps or the event itself
  const mongoId = extendedProps?._id || event.id;
  // Construct updatedEvent with image and notes
  const updatedEvent = {
    _id: mongoId,
    title: event.title,
    start: event.start,
    end: event.end,
    color: event.backgroundColor,
    image: extendedProps?.image || null, // Add image if available
    notes: extendedProps?.notes || 'No notes available', // Add notes if available
    status: extendedProps?.status || null,
    // assigned_to: (extendedProps?.assigned_resources?.assigned_to || []).map((userId) => userId.toString()),};
  //   assigned_to: Array.isArray(extendedProps?.assigned_resources?.assigned_to)
  //   ? extendedProps.assigned_resources.assigned_to.map((userId) =>
  //       userId ? userId.toString() : "Unknown User"
  //     )
  //   : [],
  // materials: Array.isArray(extendedProps?.materials) ? extendedProps.materials : [],
  // tools: Array.isArray(extendedProps?.tools) ? extendedProps.tools : [],
  // resourceIds: Array.isArray(event.resourceIds)
  //   ? event.resourceIds.filter((id) => id && id !== "undefined") // Exclude invalid entries
  //   : [],
};
 
            openForm(updatedEvent);
          },
          eventResize: async (info) => {
            if (user.access_level < 3) {
              toast.error('You do not have permission to create events.');
              return;
            }
            const { event } = info;
              try {
              const mongoId = event.extendedProps._id; // Ensure this exists
              const timezoneOffset = 3;
              const adjustedStartTime = adjustTimeForBackend(event.start, timezoneOffset);
              const adjustedEndTime = adjustTimeForBackend(event.end, timezoneOffset);
          
              const updatedEvent = {
                _id: mongoId,
                start_time: adjustedStartTime,
                end_time: adjustedEndTime,
                // Add other fields if necessary, e.g., title, color, etc.
              };
          
              await onEventUpdate(updatedEvent); // Call the provided update handler
          
              // calendarRef.current.refetchEvents(); // Optionally refetch events after update
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error updating event:', error);
              info.revert(); // Revert changes if update fails
            }
          },
          eventDrop: (info) => {
            if (user.access_level < 3) {
              toast.error('You do not have permission to create events.');
              return;
            }
            const { event, jsEvent } = info;
            const timezoneOffset = 3;
            const adjustedStartTime = adjustTimeForBackend(event.start, timezoneOffset);
            const adjustedEndTime = adjustTimeForBackend(event.end, timezoneOffset);
        
            if (jsEvent.altKey) {
              const generatedId = uuidv4();
              const duplicatedEvent = {
                ...jsEvent,
                _id: generatedId,
                start_time: adjustedStartTime,
                end_time: adjustedEndTime,
                color_code: event.backgroundColor,
                title: event.title,
              };
              onEventCreate(duplicatedEvent);
            } else {
              const mongoId = event.extendedProps._id; // Ensure this exists
              const updatedEvent = {
                _id: mongoId,
                start_time: adjustedStartTime,
                end_time: adjustedEndTime,
              };
              onEventUpdate(updatedEvent);
            }
          },},
      },
    });
    calendarRef.current.refetchEvents(); 

    // // Cleanup on Unmount
    return () => {
      if (calendarRef.current) {
        console.log("calendarRef.current",calendarRef.current)
        calendarRef.current.destroy();
        calendarRef.current = null;
      }
    };
     // Update calendar view after currentDate change
    }, [currentDate,events, assigned_resources, changedView]);
 
 
   return (
    <>
      {/* Calendar Container */}
      <div ref={calendarContainer} id="ec" />
    </>
  );
};


export default EventCalendarWrapper;


I tried setting initialDate, datesSet, and visibleRange, but it is not working as expected. If you have worked on this before, please help me.
